# Cordova project in android studio:build doesn't reflect the new changes on some files

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I've cordova android  project(angular+ionic) that is imported in android studio,when i make changes in `js` files and rebuild the project it doesn't reflect in the apk.

Still i will get the errors,however the same js files works fine in browser,
 clean the projectand rebuilding is dosen't help.

Android studio version 2.1

Comment: have you tried refreshing project follow by clean and build.

Comment: Yes I've tried that but didn't worked